# Skew a value in the range [0.0, 1.0].

Tags: functions, uniform-distribution

I have a variable *v* that can take a value from `0.0` to `1.0`. I want a function to left-skew the value, producing *w*. By "left skew" I mean that any value of *v* will be increased, but more so for lower values and less so for higher values, so that there will be more values in *w* "bunched together" the nearer you get to `1.0`. (My math is a but rusty so I apologize if I'm not asking this using the correct terminology.)

For an intuitive example (not to scale; *these are arbitrary values to explain the idea*), a value *v* of `0.4` might yield a value *w* of `0.5`, while a value *v* of `0.91` might only yield a value *w* of `0.92`. (Ideally there would be some other variable that controlled the amount of skew, and perhaps another variable that controlled the weight or slope of the skew. But I want to start simple!) However an input *v* of `0` or `1` would still yield an output *w* of `0`, and `1`, respectively (i.e. the bounds of the range are fixed).

Another way to look at this is to assume that the values in *v* are right-skewed, and we want to "unskew" them to make a uniform distribution.

This is probably Math 101 or Trigonometry 101, and there's probably some simple sin/cos function or something like that. Thank you in advance for helping my brain get oriented to review these elementary concepts.

Comment: Would a power-law function work—i.e., a mapping of the form $v \mapsto v^\gamma$? For example, $\gamma = 0.76$ yields $0.4 \mapsto 0.498$ and $0.91 \mapsto 0.931$ (all results approximate).

Comment: But $0 \mapsto 0$, which does not agree with that $v$ should be increased more for smaller values.

Comment: This is my fault for not thinking to mention this, but not only do I want 1↦1, I also want 0↦0, that is both bounds of the range are fixed.

Comment: Am I just wanting some sort of logarithmic function, with some parameters to make it meet my constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $w = v + g(v)$, where $g(v)$ is the addition to $v$ that gives $w$. Presumably, you want the following to hold for $g(v)$:

1. $g$ is defined in $[0,1]$.
2. $g(1)=0$ . This ensures that when $v$ is 1, so is $w$.
3. $g(v) \geq 0$. This ensures that $w \geq v$.
4. $-1 \leq g'(v) \leq 0$. This ensures that $v$ will be increased more for smaller $v$, and that $w$ is monotonic in $v$.

An example function that accomplishes this is
$$
g(v;r) = \frac{1}{r}\left(1-v^r \right),
$$
where $r\geq 1$ is your parameter to be fixed. I have included some examples in the image below. Smaller $r$ increases the skew.

[image]

Comment: Another example is $g(x;a) = a\left(1-x \right)$, with $0 \leq a \leq 1$.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that I'd like an input of `0` to map to `0`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for clarifying. Brian Tung's suggestion is better than mine if so. However, you may need to relax your constraint that "any value of $v$ will be increased, but more so for lower values and less so for higher values" as you are unlikely to find a smooth function $w(v)$ such that $w(v) - v$ is monotonically decreasing in $v$ for $v > 0$ if $w(0) = 0$. Ie, in Brians example, for all $0 < \gamma < 1$ there exists an $0 < \epsilon \ll 1 $ such that $\epsilon^\gamma - \epsilon < (2\epsilon)^\gamma - 2\epsilon $.

Comment: "… you may need to relax your constraint that 'any value of v will be increased, but more so for lower values and less so for higher values' …" But that's the whole point of this question. However since this will be implemented in software, it's easy enough to special-case an input of `0` to output `0`, so maybe that requirement can be suspended. Still, now that I see that it's simply a matter of finding the right curve, isn't there a curve that goes from `0.0` to `1.0`, and simply rises steeply initially and then tapers off toward the ends? Conceptually this seemed pretty simple to me.

Comment: Brian's function 'rises steeply' and 'tapers off'. The problem is in the 'rising steeply' ($w'(v) \gg 1$) section. Here, $(w(v) - v)' = w'(v) - 1 > 0$, meaning that the difference between $w$ and $v$ is increasing with $v$. Which is the opposite of what you want?

Comment: By "ensures … monotonic" do you mean that this ensures that some input doesn't "jump ahead" of the number in front of it after being put through the function?

Comment: Monotonic in this instance means that you want $w(v) - v$ to decrease as $v$ increases. This is the same as saying "any value of $v$ will be increased, but more so for lower values and less so for higher values".

Answer (score 1):

<del>Is this question really this difficult?</del> Apparently the most difficult part is visualizing graphically what I intuitively want and then explaining it.

The description below does *not* match exactly what I described above; in particular, as Philip Winchester pointed out, initially values increase more rapidly (i.e. a larger number will increase by *more* than a smaller number), until tapering off later (so that the opposite happens). I am contemplating this and determining what I actually want, and getting a better grip on graph intuition. For the meantime, here is my original (perhaps incorrect or incomplete) answer.

The responses made be realize I need to be thinking about what sort of graph I would want. And Brian Tung's comment about a power function put me on the right track—the graph of a power function was just curved the wrong way. Thinking a bit, I realized that "flipping" the graph was just a matter of subtracting from `1.0` in the appropriate places, based upon whether I wanted to flip the x or y axis. (I wanted to flip both.) Pulling out the Windows 10 graphing calculator and figuring out how to use it quickly yielded this:

$$y = 1 - (1 - x)^3$$

[image]

And I can increase the steepness of the slope just by increasing the power.

I am still contemplating exactly what I want; I'll update all of this as I come up with more understanding.

Comment: That's great that you found a solution! I hope it works for you. But in this example, it seems like $0.1 \mapsto 0.271$ (difference of $0.171$) and $0.4 \mapsto 0.784$ (difference of $0.384$). Is that what you wanted? My apologies if I have not understood your question, but that does not seem consistent with "any value of $v$ will be increased, but more so for lower values and less so for higher values".

Comment: On the face of it you seem to be correct that your (updated) values don't match what I described I wanted. I admit I haven't tried it, yet, but intuitively I'm still missing something. For lower _v_ values the slope seems to be above `1`, and for higher `v` values the slope seems to be less than one, so wouldn't that increase lower numbers more than higher numbers? haha I may be rustier than I thought. I'll think about this more to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: So it does seem that initially the number increase more rapidly—I guess that is because the slope is greater than one. But after the inflection point, somewhere in the middle, the numbers start increase more slowly, as I initially described. (Still, I'm not yet grasping that intuitively from the graph.) So am I really wanting something as simple as `y = x+k(1−x)`, which moves smaller numbers larger distances (relegating `0` to a special case)? Arg, I still don't have an intuitive grasp of how to graph what I want.

Comment: Yep, you're on the right track! Having the slope ($w'(v)$) greater than 1 is bad news since it means that $w(v)$ grows quicker than $v$, this will give you instances where $w(v_1) - v_1 < w(v_2) - v_2$, for $v_1 < v_2$ ($v_1 = 0.1$ and $v_2 = 0.4$ in my example above). $y=x+k(1-x)$ is the same as the suggestion I gave in the comment to my answer. I think it fits the bill if you relegate $0$ to a special case.